# How to compare and verify if every selected character is different for each position?

Tags: jquery

How to compare and verify if every selected caracter are different for each position ?

Each button have 5 possibility  (No, A, B, C, D) .

How to verify if A, B, C, D is already used. Knowing that "No" can be placed two times or more.

[image]

My code work only one time and I think is too complicate.
Have you a best solution ?

```
         <select id="button01" name="button01">
           <option value="No">No</option>
           <option value="A">A</option>
           <option value="B">B</option>
           <option value="C">C</option>
           <option value="D">D</option>
     </select>
     <select id="button02" name="button02">
           <option value="No">No</option>
           <option value="A">A</option>
           <option value="B">B</option>
           <option value="C">C</option>
           <option value="D">D</option>
     </select>
     <select id="button03" name="button03">
           <option value="No">No</option>
           <option value="A">A</option>
           <option value="B">B</option>
           <option value="C">C</option>
           <option value="D">D</option>
     </select>
     <select id="button04" name="button04">
           <option value="No">No</option>
           <option value="A">A</option>
           <option value="B">B</option>
           <option value="C">C</option>
           <option value="D">D</option>
     </select>
     <select id="button05" name="button05">
           <option value="No">No</option>
           <option value="A">A</option>
           <option value="B">B</option>
           <option value="C">C</option>
           <option value="D">D</option>
     </select>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("FORM#editor").on("change", function(mobile_bt) {
        // data
        var valid = false;
        var button01 = $("#button01", this);
        var button02 = $("#button02", this);
        var button03 = $("#button03", this);
        var button04 = $("#button04", this);
        var button05 = $("#button05", this);
        // compare
        if (button01.val()!= 'No') {
        valid = (button01.val() == button02.val() || button01.val() == button03.val() || button01.val() == button04.val() || button01.val() == button05.val() ? false : true);
        }
        if (button02.val()!= 'No') {

        valid = (button02.val() == button01.val() || button02.val() == button03.val() || button02.val() == button04.val() || button02.val() == button05.val() ? false : true);
        }
        if (button03.val()!= 'No') {
        valid = (button03.val() == button01.val() || button03.val() == button02.val() || button03.val() == button04.val() || button03.val() == button05.val() ? false : true);
        }
        if (button04.val()!= 'No') {
        valid = (button04.val() == button01.val() || button04.val() == button02.val() || button04.val() == button03.val() || button04.val() == button05.val() ? false : true);
        }
        if (button05.val()!= 'No') {
        valid = (button05.val() == button01.val() || button05.val() == button02.val() || button05.val() == button03.val() && button05.val() == button04.val() ? false : true);
        }
        // Alert
        if ( !valid ) {
            // Stop
            mobile_bt.preventDefault();
            // display alert
            alert("Warning! 2 or more buttons are assigned to the same location. Please change your choice.");
            // Focus back
            $("#button01").focus();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
$("select[id^='button']").on("change", function(mobile_bt) {
    var fullList = $("select[id^='button']").map(function() { return $(this).val() }).get()
        uniqueList = fullList.filter(function(item, index) {
                        return (item == 'No') ? item : fullList.indexOf(item) >= index;
                     });
    if(fullList.length != uniqueList.length){
        Your code here...
    }       
});
```

(Step 1) Map all of the values to an array.

(Step 2) Filter the duplicates if the value isn't 'No'.

(Step 3) Compare the two array lengths to determine if there was a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
You're right, it's an excellent example that works perfectly and much simpler than my code.  You did an magnificent syntax.Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Canta You're welcome. Could you mark this as the accepted answer if it fully solves your problem?